# Delete zeros in a list with different dimensionality

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, multidimensional-array

Somehow I come up with a list with different dimensionality, containing zeros and non-zeros, how can I delete the zeros and get a list containing the non-zeros without changing orders? Say, I have

```
a=[array([0.]), array([ 0.        , 1]), array([ 0.        ,  0.        , 19]), array([ 0.        ,  0.        , 5, 4]), 5, 100, 16, 7, 7, 7, 9, 1, 9]
```

And I want

```
[1,19,5,4,5,100,16,7,7,7,9,1,9]
```

I tried

```
np.concatenate(a).tolist()
```

but it tells

```
all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

Anyone could help with this? Thank you.

Comment: *Your arrays* have the same dimensionality (they are all 1-dimensional). The problem is that you are trying to concatenate them with *plain integers* (functionally, *0*-dimensional arrays).

Comment: You should probably fix whatever is generating that list to begin with...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure it can be done without some sort of loop:

```
arr = np.concatenate([i if isinstance(i, np.ndarray) else [i] for i in a])                                                                                                                                                           
arr[arr != 0].astype(int).tolist()
```

Output:

```
[1, 19, 5, 4, 5, 100, 16, 7, 7, 7, 9, 1, 9]
```

Alternatively, if you can use `pandas`:

```
from pandas.core.common import flatten                                                                                                                                                                                          

out = [int(i) for i in flatten(a) if i]
```